# Eclipse question - panels don't get restored when double clicking

Tags: eclipse, ide

You know how, in Eclipse, when you double click on a file tab (which shows the class name), the editor gets expanded to the whole screen minimizing other panels? Well normally I just double click again on the tab to restore everything, but all of the sudden double clicking again doesnt do anything (the editor remains in full screen and all other panels minimized)!

I am not sure what I did to cause this.  Any ideas how to get it back to normal? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this menu option:

**Window->Navigation->Maximize Active View or Editor**

The keyboard shortcut for this menu is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

UPDATE: If the above fails, try restarting Eclipse. That will most likely get it out of whatever funk it is in.

Comment: This has the same effect as double click on the tab: I can see the min/max icon on the top right of the editor switching modes, but the editor stays maximized.

Comment: Turns out restarting eclipse fixed the problem...I didn't think it would make a difference, but it did.

Comment: Ah, yes, I should've put that in my answer too. I will do that now

Answer (score 9):

You might try "Reset Perspective" in the "Window" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have icons at the end that allow you to minimize and restore? If you do click on restore. It should also be available as a contextual menu item on the editor tab itself.